# remove duplicate description in group by with rollup in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to achieve what is in the image attached. The duplicated names do not look good. For example, there are many year 2000, I only need the top one. I want to remove the other year 2000. How can I do it?

[Click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPA0V.png)

```
SELECT
         IF(GROUPING(year), 'All years', year) AS year,
         IF(GROUPING(country), 'All countries', country) AS country,
         IF(GROUPING(product), 'All products', product) AS product,
         SUM(profit) AS profit
         FROM sales
         GROUP BY year, country, product WITH ROLLUP;

+-----------+---------------+--------------+--------+
| year      | country       | product      | profit |
+-----------+---------------+--------------+--------+
| 2000      | Finland       | Computer     |   1500 |
| 2000      | Finland       | Phone        |    100 |
| 2000      | Finland       | All products |   1600 |
| 2000      | India         | Calculator   |    150 |
| 2000      | India         | Computer     |   1200 |
| 2000      | India         | All products |   1350 |
| 2000      | USA           | Calculator   |     75 |
| 2000      | USA           | Computer     |   1500 |
| 2000      | USA           | All products |   1575 |
| 2000      | All countries | All products |   4525 |
| 2001      | Finland       | Phone        |     10 |
| 2001      | Finland       | All products |     10 |
| 2001      | USA           | Calculator   |     50 |
| 2001      | USA           | Computer     |   2700 |
| 2001      | USA           | TV           |    250 |
| 2001      | USA           | All products |   3000 |
| 2001      | All countries | All products |   3010 |
| All years | All countries | All products |   7535 |
+-----------+---------------+--------------+--------+
```

Comment: What output do you want here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , please click on the image. It shows there